# How to order and partition by 2+ columns and then select a random sample based on N number of ranks in the sample?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL.

I have a table with 2 columns in this example:
[image]

I want to add a new column with a unique id corresponding to partitions by name and category as shown in the result. Then, I want to take a random sample choosing 2 (or more) unique ids because under each unique id, there will be a lot of other historical data.

I have tried this so far, but I get **1s for everything**. I'm missing something really simple here, but how do I correct my mistake? I have to do this operation for several million rows in the real table.

```
SELECT
  dense_rank() over (partition by name, category order by category) as unique_id,
  *
FROM
 example_table
```

After this, presumably I'll have to use RAND() somewhere but how do I do this?

This is my naive approach to get the solution in the above pic.

```
with ranks (
  ...
)

select * from ranks where unique_id = 2 or unique_id = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function better.

```
SELECT
    name, 
    category,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, category ORDER BY name, category) unique_id
FROM
    test;
```

> ```
> name | category | unique_id
> :--- | :------- | --------:
> A    | Alpha    |         1
> A    | Alpha    |         2
> A    | Alpha    |         3
> A    | Beta     |         1
> A    | Beta     |         2
> B    | Alpha    |         1
> B    | Alpha    |         2
> B    | Theta    |         1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a59008461c187318a1f4f594ed38872)*

To get a unique_id for each pair of name-category, remove the PARTITION part and use only ORDER BY:

```
SELECT
    name, 
    category,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, category) unique_id
FROM
    test;
```

> ```
> name | category | unique_id
> :--- | :------- | --------:
> A    | Alpha    |         1
> A    | Alpha    |         1
> A    | Alpha    |         1
> A    | Beta     |         2
> A    | Beta     |         2
> B    | Alpha    |         3
> B    | Alpha    |         3
> B    | Theta    |         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff11fab48aa289fdfe5a2c198eeca9e0)*

To select two rows of each unique_id: (As far as I've not used any order it is supposed to be random)

```
WITH ct AS
(
  SELECT
      name, 
      category,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, category) unique_id
  FROM
      test
)
SELECT
    a.unique_id, c.name, c.category
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT unique_id
     FROM ct) a
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT b.name, b.category 
              FROM   ct b
              WHERE  b.unique_id = a.unique_id 
              LIMIT 2) c ON TRUE
ORDER BY
    a.unique_id;
```

> ```
> unique_id | name | category
> --------: | :--- | :-------
>         1 | A    | Alpha   
>         1 | A    | Alpha   
>         2 | A    | Beta    
>         2 | A    | Beta    
>         3 | B    | Alpha   
>         3 | B    | Alpha   
>         4 | B    | Theta
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7c5f2f3a7d2723f426cb0da3cba6a69f)*